Kyber implementation possible overflow in the NTT subroutine?
I took a look at the code from Kyber, which I would like to quote here:
/*************************************************
* Name:        ntt
*
* Description: Inplace number-theoretic transform (NTT) in Rq
*              input is in standard order, output is in bitreversed order
*
* Arguments:   - int16_t r[256]: pointer to input/output vector of elements
*                                of Zq
**************************************************/
void ntt(int16_t r[256]) {
  unsigned int len, start, j, k;
  int16_t t, zeta;

  k = 1;
  for(len = 128; len >= 2; len >>= 1) {
    for(start = 0; start < 256; start = j + len) {
      zeta = zetas[k++];
      for(j = start; j < start + len; ++j) {
        t = fqmul(zeta, r[j + len]);
        r[j + len] = r[j] - t;
        r[j] = r[j] + t;
      }
    }
  }
}

In Kyber we work with the modulus $q=3329$, so at this point:
r[j + len] = r[j] - t;
r[j] = r[j] + t;

I would have expected (or something similar):
r[j + len] = (r[j] - t) % q;
r[j] = (r[j] + t) %q;

My question is now, how is a possible overflow prevented in the NTT from the initial code if no reductions take place? Or to put it another way, why are the lines in particular not reduced with modulo? Is there a special reason why a modulo operation has been omitted here? As a more performant alternative to the naive modulo calculation, the Barrett reduction could have been used at the points, why was this not done?
Example: The array r contains values in int16_t and therefore in the range $-32,768 ... 32,767$, if you add $q=3329$ now $10$ times ($3329 \cdot 10 = 33290$) without performing a reduction you have an overflow. The scenario may seem somewhat constructed, but I don't see any mechanism in the code that prevents this...

Note that modular numbers in Kyber are not represented as residues ${0,\dots, 3329 - 1}$, but instead as "balanced" representatives (roughly ${-q/2,\dots, q/2}$). Also, one can generally argue probabilistically that adding $n$ uniform elements mod q grows not to $\approx nq$ (as you would get worst-case), but instead $\approx \sqrt{n} q$ with probability all but $\exp(-n)$. I don't remember Kyber making this argument, but some other schemes (Saber) did, at least for some implementations of their multiplication

@MarkSchultz-Wu: I agree with your 'balanced representation' comment.  However, if that were not the case, then your claim of probabilistic behavior of the uniform elements would be wrong - during Kyber decryption, the decryptor applies NTT to attacker chosen data.  Obviously, the attacker could choose a radically nonuniform input.

len runs through the seven values 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2. For each value of len each element of r is updated once, so from where do you get the factor 10?

@MarkSchultz-Wu I am not entirely satisfied with the probabilistic argument. Because a real overflow cannot be ruled out.

@garfunkel The 10 results from the fact that in the "worst case" you can add the number q=3329 10 times until you have an overflow (see 16 bit from int16_t). If you have a vector with, say, only values of 3328 and calculate the NTT off this, there must be an overflow in my opinion.

@P_Gate lattices are not 100% correct in the first place though. Focusing on 100% chance of no overflow seems odd when the rest of the scheme is only correct with high probability. Anyway, formal details for the probabilistsic argument are in the paper NTT multiplication for NTT unfriendly rings, though this mostly works with bounding the probability of overflow during polynomial multiplication, where it is higher than scalar addition.

@P_Gate Did you check the usage of ntt() in the rest of the project? If the input is normed as described by Mark, and the output gets normed by the callee, no overflow occurrs.
